# jQuery Actions on different div.onHover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must say that I am beginner in jquery but I usually try to figure out and solve problems by myself. However now I have a problem and i am stuck

I have a jquery function that rotate images inside div `.break_rotate`

```
var divs = $('div[class^="break_rotate"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(4000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

Now. I am trying to stop this function when I hover over another div. For example #div2

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which _actually_ describes the problem you're facing.

Comment: on hover do this .. `$('div[class^="break_rotate"]').stop()` ?

Answer (score 0):

add a varible to check if u should rotate or not, set this varible value in the events .mouseenter and .mouseleave

```
var allowrotate = true;

$('.break_rotate').mouseenter(function() {  
   allowrotate = false;
});

$('.break_rotate').mouseleave(function() {  
   allowrotate = true;
});

(function cycle() { 

if(allowrotate){
divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
          .delay(4000)
          .fadeOut(400, cycle);

i = ++i % divs.length;
}

})();
```